# Convert comma separated values in a cell to a table in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to convert a cell with values separated by commas to table format that can be imported into a database or for a pivot

e.g.

```
Column 1     Column 2
Group A      Model 1, Model 2, Model 3
Group B      Model 4, Model 5, Model 6, Model 7
```

I need it as

```
Column 1    Column 2
Group A     Model 1
Group A     Model 2
Group A     Model 3
Group B     Model 4
Group B     Model 5
Group B     Model 6
```

Some rows will have as many as 120 models. How can I do this?

Comment: Would you consider using a macro??

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way might be to use a text editor to replace commas with line breaks. Then all your data will be in columns and you just have to enforce the group names. You can do this with a third column to fill in from above where the group name is blank.